# Problem with custom action on selected text in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intentfilter

In my app I use Java and Kotlin. I created `intent-filter` with `android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT` and in java Fragment after select text I see my action but in Kotlin fragment there is only COPY and SHARE. Here is my intent-filter:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.user.ProcessTextActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_new_action"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Of course textView have set: `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.
Both fragments(Java and Kotlin) are in this same activity.

Comment: That `<intent-filter>` is to provide options to *other apps*, more so than your own. Beyond that, you should look to see what differences are between the layouts used by the fragments or other differences in your test scenarios (e.g., landscape vs. portrait).

Comment: @CommonsWare the layouts are this same and a use only portrait orientatnion

Comment: You might consider creating a sample project that can reproduce the problem, then file an issue, perhaps against AppCompat. The behavior of `TextView` and `EditText` should be independent of whether you are writing in Java, Kotlin, Scala, Clojure, or whatever, because the framework should be handling this context menu.

Comment: I know but something is wrong

Comment: That is why it would be helpful if you created a sample project that can reproduce the problem, then file an issue with that sample project. If you think of it, post a link to the issue here, so we can try out the sample and see if we see the same results.

Answer (score 0):

In order for other actions (than (COPY and SHARE)) to be visible, you must add the id for TextView in XML file